# tried to redefine existing error around graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, graphql-schema

I have 2 project(graphql client) with schema.graphqls each fro different graphql endpoints, and have some same definitions.

Project A
--schema.graphqls
--type Order...
type Product...
Project B
--schema.graphqls
--type order...
type Product...

The project A and B managed by a parent project like below

```
<modules>
    <module>../projectA</module>
    <module>../proejctB</module>
```

So, when I run one of the 2 project will throw the error below

```
There are problems with the GraphQL Schema:
     * 'Mutation' type [@307:1] tried to redefine existing 'Mutation' type [@10:1]
     * 'Order' type [@374:1] tried to redefine existing 'Order' type [@455:1]
     * 'OrderConnection' type [@421:1] tried to redefine existing 'OrderConnection' type [@439:1]
     * 'OrderEdge' type [@429:1] tried to redefine existing 'OrderEdge' type [@447:1]
     * 'PaymentMethod' type [@502:1] tried to redefine existing 'PaymentMethod' type [@501:1]
     * 'Product' type [@518:1] tried to redefine existing 'Product' type [@571:1]
```

How can I resolve the issue? Thanks a lot!